# org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException: Table "BOOKMARKS" not found; SQL statement:

Tags: spring-boot, h2

I'm trying to create a springboot application with h2 in-memory db.
when I start my application and query the database, I see the table is not created.
I get the error

```
org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException: Table "BOOKMARKS" not found; SQL statement:
select bookmark0_.id as id1_0_, bookmark0_.created_at as created_2_0_, bookmark0_.title as title3_0_, bookmark0_.url as url4_0_ from bookmarks bookmark0_ [42102-212]
at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:502) ~[h2-2.1.212.jar:2.1.212]
at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:477) ~[h2-2.1.212.jar:2.1.212]
at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:223) ~[h2-2.1.212.jar:2.1.212]
at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:199) ~[h2-2.1.212.jar:2.1.212]
at org.h2.command.Parser.getTableOrViewNotFoundDbException(Parser.java:8376) ~[h2-2.1.212.jar:2.1.212]
at org.h2.command.Parser.getTableOrViewNotFoundDbException(Parser.java:8347) ~[h2-2.1.212.jar:2.1.212]
at org.h2.command.Parser.readTableOrView(Parser.java:8336) ~[h2-2.1.212.jar:2.1.212]
at org.h2.command.Parser.readTablePrimary(Parser.java:1883) ~[h2-2.1.212.jar:2.1.212]
at org.h2.command.Parser.readTableReference(Parser.java:2359) ~[h2-2.1.212.jar:2.1.212]
at org.h2.command.Parser.parseSelectFromPart(Parser.java:2810) ~[h2-2.1.212.jar:2.1.212]
at org.h2.command.Parser.parseSelect(Parser.java:2917) ~[h2-2.1.212.jar:2.1.212]
at org.h2.command.Parser.parseQueryPrimary(Parser.java:2800) ~[h2-2.1.212.jar:2.1.212]
at org.h2.command.Parser.parseQueryTerm(Parser.java:2667) ~[h2-2.1.212.jar:2.1.212]
at org.h2.command.Parser.parseQueryExpressionBody(Parser.java:2646) ~[h2-2.1.212.jar:2.1.212]
at org.h2.command.Parser.parseQueryExpressionBodyAndEndOfQuery(Parser.java:2639) ~[h2-2.1.212.jar:2.1.212]
at org.h2.command.Parser.parseQueryExpression(Parser.java:2632) ~[h2-2.1.212.jar:2.1.212]
at org.h2.command.Parser.parseQuery(Parser.java:2593) ~[h2-2.1.212.jar:2.1.212]
at org.h2.command.Parser.parsePrepared(Parser.java:724) ~[h2-2.1.212.jar:2.1.212]
at org.h2.command.Parser.parse(Parser.java:691) ~[h2-2.1.212.jar:2.1.212]
at org.h2.command.Parser.parse(Parser.java:661) ~[h2-2.1.212.jar:2.1.212]
at org.h2.command.Parser.prepareCommand(Parser.java:568) ~[h2-2.1.212.jar:2.1.212]
at org.h2.engine.SessionLocal.prepareLocal(SessionLocal.java:631) ~[h2-2.1.212.jar:2.1.212]
at org.h2.engine.SessionLocal.prepareCommand(SessionLocal.java:554) ~[h2-2.1.212.jar:2.1.212]
at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.prepareCommand(JdbcConnection.java:1116) ~[h2-2.1.212.jar:2.1.212]
at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcPreparedStatement.<init>(JdbcPreparedStatement.java:92) ~[h2-2.1.212.jar:2.1.212]
at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.prepareStatement(JdbcConnection.java:288) ~[h2-2.1.212.jar:2.1.212]
at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyConnection.prepareStatement(ProxyConnection.java:337) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]
at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyConnection.prepareStatement(HikariProxyConnection.java) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$5.doPrepare(StatementPreparerImpl.java:149) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar:5.6.9.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$StatementPreparationTemplate.prepareStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:176) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar:5.6.9.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl.prepareQueryStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:151) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar:5.6.9.Final]
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.prepareQueryStatement(Loader.java:2122) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar:5.6.9.Final]
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:2059) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar:5.6.9.Final]
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:2037) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar:5.6.9.Final]
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:956) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar:5.6.9.Final]
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:357) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar:5.6.9.Final]
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2868) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar:5.6.9.Final]
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2850) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar:5.6.9.Final]
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2682) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar:5.6.9.Final]
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2677) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar:5.6.9.Final]
at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:540) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar:5.6.9.Final]
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:400) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar:5.6.9.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:219) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar:5.6.9.Final]
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1459) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar:5.6.9.Final]
at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.doList(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1649) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar:5.6.9.Final]
at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.list(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1617) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar:5.6.9.Final]
at org.hibernate.query.Query.getResultList(Query.java:165) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar:5.6.9.Final]
at org.hibernate.query.criteria.internal.compile.CriteriaQueryTypeQueryAdapter.getResultList(CriteriaQueryTypeQueryAdapter.java:76) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar:5.6.9.Final]
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.findAll(SimpleJpaRepository.java:427) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.7.0.jar:2.7.0]
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.findAll(SimpleJpaRepository.java:88) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.7.0.jar:2.7.0]
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker$RepositoryFragmentMethodInvoker.lambda$new$0(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:289) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.0.jar:2.7.0]
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.doInvoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:137) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.0.jar:2.7.0]
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.invoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:121) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.0.jar:2.7.0]
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition$RepositoryFragments.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:529) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.0.jar:2.7.0]
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:285) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.0.jar:2.7.0]
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$ImplementationMethodExecutionInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:639) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.0.jar:2.7.0]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:163) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.0.jar:2.7.0]
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:138) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.0.jar:2.7.0]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:80) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.0.jar:2.7.0]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:123) ~[spring-tx-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:388) ~[spring-tx-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:119) ~[spring-tx-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:137) ~[spring-tx-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:174) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.7.0.jar:2.7.0]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:97) ~[spring-aop-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:215) ~[spring-aop-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
at jdk.proxy3/jdk.proxy3.$Proxy125.findAll(Unknown Source) ~[na:an]
```

i have these properties in my application.properties

```
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl.auto=update
```

i changed to `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl.auto=create` and `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl.auto=create-drop` it does not seem to create the table.

also when i open http://localhost:8080/h2-console/ and connect i get the error `Database "C:/Users/manjo/test" not found, either pre-create it or allow remote database creation (not recommended in secure environments) [90149-212] 90149/90149`

Here is my entity class:

```
package com.manjosh.kube.bookmarker.domain;



import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Setter;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.time.Instant;


@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name="bookmarks")
public class Bookmark {
@Id
@SequenceGenerator(name = "bm_id_seq_gen",sequenceName = "bm_id_seq")
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE,generator = "bm_id_seq_gen")
private Long id;
@Column(nullable = false)
private String title;
@Column(nullable = false)
private String url;
private Instant createdAt;
}
```

I'm using springboot 2.7.0 and h2

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had postgress dependency in my pom.xml

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Once i removed this dependency, its creating the tables while starting.